# SOQL join question

Tags: soql

Not sure how to handle this in SOQL:

There are Customer objects and Order objects.  A customer can have many orders

I want to select the DollarValue__c of each customer's oldest order?

I'm thinking something like this but it's wrong.

```
select DollarValue__c, min(OrderTime__c) from Order__c group by customer__r.id
```

Comment: Were you here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested query. Try this:

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT DollarValue__c FROM Orders__r ORDER BY OrderTime__c LIMIT 1) FROM Customer__c]
```

And then for each `Customer__c` record you can access the list of Orders which will only consist of 1 record, the oldest one:

```
if (customer.Orders__r.size() == 1) 
{
    // The oldest order for this customer
    customer.Orders__r[0].DollarValue__c; 
}
```